# How is the input tensor for TensorFlow's tf.nn.dynamic_rnn operator structured?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to write a language model using word embeddings and recursive neural networks in TensorFlow 0.9.0 using the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` graph operation, but I don't understand how the `input` tensor is structured.

Let's say I have a corpus of *n* words. I embed each word in a vector of length *e*, and I want my RNN to unroll to *t* time steps. Assuming I use the default `time_major = False` parameter, what shape would my `input` tensor `[batch_size, max_time, input_size]` have?

Maybe a specific tiny example will make this question clearer. Say I have a corpus consisting of *n=8* words that looks like this.

```
1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2
```

Say I embed it in a vector of size *e=3* with the embeddings 1 -> [10, 10, 10], 2 -> [20, 20, 20], and 3 -> [30, 30, 30], what would my `input` tensor look like?

I've read the [TensorFlow Recurrent Neural Network tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks), but that doesn't use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. I've also read the documentation for `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, but find it confusing. In particular I'm not sure what "max_time" and "input_size" mean here.

Can anyone give the shape of the `input` tensor in terms of *n*, *t*, and *e*, and/or an example of what that tensor would look like initialized with data from the small corpus I describe?

*TensorFlow 0.9.0, Python 3.5.1, OS X 10.11.5*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it looks like `batch_size = 1`, since you're looking at a single example.  So `max_time` is `n=8` and `input_size` is the input depth, in your case `e=3`.  So you would want to construct an `input` tensor which is shaped `[1, 8, 3]`.  It's batch_major, so the first dimension (the batch dimension) is `1`.  If, say, you had another input at the same time, with `n=6` words, then you would combine the two by padding this second example to `8` words (by padding zeros for the last 2 word embeddings) and you would have an `inputs` size of `[2, 8, 3]`.

Comment: Does that mean your entire training set has to go into a single tensor? Wouldn't that cause memory problems for really big training sets?

Comment: No; you can train in minibatches; i.e., in sets of 16 or 32 examples at a time.  see `tf.batch` and `tf.batch_join` and specifically for this discussion the argument `dynamic_pad=True`.

Comment: Is the idea that for small data sets you use the simple `feed_dict` mechanism, but when you scale up to large sets you need to use a file reading pipeline?   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files

Comment: That's one way of looking at it it.  Another reason you may want to use the file reading pipeline is if you're performing distributed training using a Kubernetes cluster; in this case, the suggested approach is to shard your training data into multiple files and use `tf.train.string_input_producer` so each worker gets a different shard to work off.  Basically the tooling exists for parallel data reading within TensorFlow, so you don't have to manually figure out which subset of the data each worker should get minibatches from.

Comment: I actually didn't intend a batch size of 1. Clearer reformulation of the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493468/what-are-the-parameters-of-tensorflows-dynamic-rnn-for-this-simple-data-set.